# Sending Data Between Windows Service and Web Application

Tags: asp.net, winforms, wcf, webforms, windows-services

just a quick question hopefully someone can point me in the right direction. In our .net web application we are trying to implement a third party device that pairs with the user computer. In order to generate this pair in our project we need to be able to either pull the current users computer name, or ip address. In a winforms application this would be easier since it resides on the users network. Since this is a web application, it has been quite hard as the only thing being returned is the ip address of the server or the name of the server. So what we are thinking of doing now is having either a Windows Service, or WinForms application, that our customers can download that will return this information to our application.

Creating the Windows Service or WInForms application is straight forward and I understand that, my question is how would I get my Windows Service or WinForms application to send data to the web application? I have looked into WCF but it seems the end user would have to set up some tcp settings on their end which could be difficult for some and I would like to avoid. If anyone has any suggestions other than WCF I'm open to that as well.

Any suggestions for how this situation should be handled appreciated, thanks.

Comment: what if you explain what are you trying to do, a full example, and i will tell you how.

Comment: Im trying to get the users computer name or ip address. Since this is hard to do through the web server I was thinking of creating a Windows Service for customers to install on their end. This service will get the computer name, the web application will then grab the computer name from this window service and use that to pair with the third party device through the application

Comment: ok i answer on bottom

Answer (score 0):

i guess you are misunderstanding the concept of Web service, or WCF or whatever technology you use.

A Web Service is that, a "function" that will be called from a client but executing on the server, so when you do a WCF and you use it from a different web site, or a desktop app, you are in fact sending the data to that server.

In other case if you are trying to achieve a "real time" monitor, sending data to the server and showing it on your website, then you need to do separate things.

This is what you need to do.

First set up a WCF service that will handle the information on your SERVER side, in there you need to implement a function which will be receiving a IP and computer name (or whatever you need) and returning the hash, key or the info you are using to pair the device, then host it on a IIS server.

`public string PairDevice (string name, string IP, string ....){

```
//save to database, do something and return the hash.
```

}`

Second create a windows service, a desktop application or something that will be running on the CLIENT computer, in there you need to CONSUME the WCF, in your main code, you will retrieve all the parameters you need for your WCF function, then adding a "Service Reference", you will be available to use the REMOTE function on your CLIENT, be aware that your SERVICE needs to be reachable by the application.

`//retrieve IP, name, etc
    string name;
    string ip;
    myWCFclass WCF= new myWCFclass();
    string myHash=WCF.PairDevice (name,ip,etc...);
    //thats all.`

And that's all you gotta do, if you need more help about how WCF works, i suggest you to read this link

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/406096/A-beginners-tutorial-for-understanding-Windows

Comment: So @thepanch if I understand correctly the Windows Service would send data to my WCF(or Web Service) then WCF would save it to database or a file?

Comment: I can host the that in a Windows Service cant I?

Comment: NO, you cant host a WCF in Windows Service it needs to be "visible" so you need to place it on a IIS.